# Hive results save as parquet file

Tags: hive, parquet, snappy

I'm trying to create a snappy.parquet file from a Hive table. Its a big partitioned table just need small part of it. Doing this:

```
set parquet.compression=SNAPPY;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true;
set mapred.compress.map.output=true;
set mapreduce.map.output.compress=true;
set mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type=BLOCK;
set io.seqfile.compression.type = BLOCK;
insert overwrite directory 'EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY' STORED AS PARQUET select * from SOURCE_TABLE;
```

It creates 000000_0 file with following schema:

```
message hive_schema {
optional int32 _col0;
optional binary _col1 (UTF8);
optional binary _col2 (UTF8);
optional binary _col3 (UTF8);
optional binary _col4 (UTF8);
optional binary _col5 (UTF8);
optional binary _col6 (UTF8);
optional binary _col7 (UTF8);
optional int64 _col8;
optional int64 _col9;
optional int64 _col10;
)
```

Loosing all the column names from SOURCE_TABLE. How do i save it properly so i can use it as hive table later?

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying to create a new data set which is sourcing from only one partition of a larger source data set, correct? If so i would just create a new external hive table which is selecting all the data from the specific table you are after. Then you will have a table and a directory/files available for use.

Comment: Yea i'm trying to create small data set from couple partitions of the big table. I'll try creating new hive table first and select into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new external table for your data set by selecting all the data from the source partitions you are after. Then you would have a table and file that can be utilized. You can't do a create table as select statement as of now with external tables, so you would need to create the table first and then load data into it.

```
create external table yourNewTable ( use your source table DDL...)
  stored as parquet location '/yourNewLocation';

insert into yourNewTable
  select * from yourSourceTable where yourPartitionedFieldNames = 'desiredPartitionName';
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error occurred executing hive query: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10071]: Inserting into a external table is not allowed`

Comment: Tried to do insert OVERWRITE table with same error. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Ensure that the property set hive.insert.into.external.tables = true